# Someone please can see why the following prepared statment returns nothing?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link,"
    SELECT *
      FROM ads
     INNER JOIN dept ON dept.id_dept = ads.in_dpt
     INNER JOIN members ON members.idMem = ads.from_Mem
     INNER JOIN sub_cat_ad ON id_sub_cat = ads.ads_in_Cat
     INNER JOIN cat_ad ON idCat_ad = sub_cat_ad.from_cat_ad
     WHERE ads_in_Cat = ? ");

if(isset($_GET['fromSCat'])){
    $fromSCat = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_GET['fromSCat']);
}

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'i',$fromSCat);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

$tot=mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt); //Ouput: 0
```

**Without the prepared statement, it's ok**

Comment: That code was very poorly laid-out. Please make an effort to format it properly in future. Don't make people work so hard to help you.

Comment: Sorry! for that and thanks. But the question was why $tot returns 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the reason it's returning 0, but you're double-escaping `$fromSCat` - you don't need escape_string in prepared statements, bind_param does that already.  Try commenting out the escape_string & see what happens.

Also, you might want to scoot the bind/exec/fetch calls inside your `if` statement, unless `$fromSCat` is being defined earlier in the script.

---

**Followup re comment**:  that error means your database is sketchy.  Do you have primary keys & indexes on the relevant tables?  mysqli is a little odd for throwing an exception over it, it's not any of it's business.  If you don't have access to fix up the DB tables, add [`mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF);`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-report.php) near the top of the script.

(also, if you can: use [PDO](http://www.php.net/pdo) instead.  It's better & cleaner in both syntax and documentation.)

Comment: Thanks for you help, i eliminated mysqli_real..., now i m getting this error:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'No index used in query/prepared statement

Answer (score 1):

You've got the [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) parameters backwards. it's `($string_to_escape, $optional_database_handle)`. So you're trying to query against something like `WHERE ads_in_Cat='Resource #1'` instead of your $_GET parameter.

Comment: Note the i, different library (http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).  It's technically not backwards, just really confusing.

Comment: Ah yeah... silly little 'i'... Another thing catching my eye: You're executing a fetch() call, and THEN calling ...num_rows(). Perhaps the resulting row's already been consumed from the result set by then and num_rows() is properly returning '0 rows remaining'.

Comment: Thanks for you help, i eliminated mysqli_real..., now i m getting this error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'No index used in query/prepared statement